# mysql query to select data from table2 which does not exist in table1

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables `table1` and `table2`, where `table1` contains the data collected so far, and `table2` contains `table1`'s data along with some updated/additional data. I need to retrieve only this updated/additional data and insert it into `table1`.

Now I know I can use `NOT IN` to do this, but I am not sure it will be a very efficient solution in case of a huge number of records. Any suggestion on what the best approach would be in terms of execution speed?

Comment: Please be more specific with your question. Adding table schema, dummy records, and your desired result would help SO community understand questions clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `simple join` both tables

something like below:

```
select t1.* from table1 as t1 join table2 as t2 on t1.id=t2.id where ...[]
```

Comment: One more thing - the join must be LEFT OUTER JOIN, not INNER.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i've understand your question correctly but let me give it a try. Suppose you have a design like this:

```
TableA : {colA, colB, colC, colD, colE}
TableB : {colA, colB, RecC, RecD, RecE}
```

where Tables (`tableA`, `tableB`) is joined on `ColA`. I Assumed that `TableA`'s columns (`colC`, `ColD`, `colE`) will be updated and the records are based on `TableB`'s columns (`recC`, `recD`, `recE`).

In your statement: *I need to retrieve only this updated/additional data and insert it into table1.*. I think you want to update `TableA`'s records based on `TableB`

```
UPDATE TableA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.ColA = b.ColA
SET    a.ColC = b.RecC,
       a.ColD = b.RecD,
       a.ColE = b.RecE
-- WHERE (Condition)          -- if you want to have a condition.
```

so the statement above updates all the records in `tableA` **if** `colA` also exist in `tableB` since I've used `INNER JOIN`. You could also use `LEFT JOIN`.